# How to retrieve the contents of a single document from firestore documents by angularfire2

Tags: angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

Maybe this is a stupid question but i cannot find a suitable answer for whole day. Anyone please help if you know.

May i know how to retrieve value from the single documents.

```
user
    ->id
        ->name: kevin
        ->role: employee
        ->gender: m
```

How can i get role's value  for further processing, as no instruction from the official website.

Comment: The Firestore documentation provides a pretty good introduction to reading documents: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data. I assume you've read those and tried it, but without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it'll be hard to help better than the documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I have read that one actually. That is exactly the way i want to retrieve the value. However i cannot find way by using angularfire2 so i wont import again official firestore into it.

Maybe it means i need to combine the firestore doc and angularfire2 together in order to work for it, right?

Comment: Here is the angularfire2 official doc for handling [documents](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md). if its not working show what you have done.